# c# application and configuration settings

Tags: c#, settings

I never used `Settings` class before but I found some articles on CodeProject which I'm currently reading (for example http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/PropertiesSettings.aspx) but so far I didn't see how to save `string` array for getting it after application is started next time.

For example my application has several `FileSystemWatcher` instances, with each instance several other directories are connected (for example one FSW instance is monitoring one directory for a change and when it happens it copies some file to several other directories), so I would have one `string` array with watched paths representing FSW instances, and `string` array for each of those paths, representing directories that are affected.

My question is, what should I use (`Settings` class or something else), and how should I use that for storing application configuration that is variable number of `string` arrays? Emphasize is on something I could use very soon as I don't have too much time to make custom class (but would have to if I cannot find solution) or dig into some obscure hacks.
Any tutorial link, code snippet would be very helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use a config file instead? I had a set of FileSystemWatchers like yours and just added a set of paths using [custom config sections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tw134k3.aspx). Thought that requires you rolling a class to extending the Configuration classes, but I think that you can't beat that approach.

Though if you want a clear easy hack and don't want to get bothered with the Custom Config Sections/Elements/Collections. Just use a quick and easy AppSettings hack. XD

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="ConnectionInfo0" value="server=(local);database=Northwind;Integrated Security=SSPI" />
    <add key="ConnectionInfo1" value="server=(local);database=Northwind;Integrated Security=SSPI" />
    <add key="ConnectionInfo2" value="server=(local);database=Northwind;Integrated Security=SSPI" />
</appSettings>
```

Getting it from code.

```
const string CONNECTIONSTRING="";
int i = 0;
while(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["ConnectionInfo"] + i != null)
{
    // do stuff with connection info here
    // use
    ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["ConnectionInfo" + i];
    // to get data.
    ++i;
}
```

Tad ugly, I know. Custom Config works best.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Jonn. Thing is I need to add data programmatically also and since I simply don't have so much time now to spend on learning how to do this correctly (IMO they over-complicated it), I will use `System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer` for now. It's cleaner and much easier to use/deploy with custom class which represents settings. Cheers.